# Breadcrumbs in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, breadcrumbs

I use HtmlHelper from CakePHP to create breadcrumbs navigation for my page...
And i set `$html->getCrumbs('separator', 'Home Page')` to `default.ctp` and in other views i set `$html->addCrumbs('nameLink', 'linkUrl');`
All works fine!

But when I open my Home Page there is no breadcrumbs, why?

Comment: I assume you echo the helper? echo $html->getCrumbs() otherwise you'll not see anything ;)

Answer (score 2):

Extremely obvious answer, but does your homepage view have any calls to `$html->addCrumb()`? Regardless of whether you pass "Home Page" as the second parameter to `$html->getCrumbs()`, if you haven't added any crumbs in your view, `$html->getCrumbs()` will output nothing.

[See the method definition.](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/html-helper/#line-412)

The purpose of the second parameter of `$html->getCrumbs()` is to output something like "Breadcrumbs:" or "How you got here:", not to display the first of your crumbs.